# How to make the database giving me two datas

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Hello my Database (Sqlite3) is giving me just one data from all the database, I want it to give me all datas but I don't know why It didn't, here's what I tried

```
    c.execute("SELECT type FROM accounts")
    acctype = c.fetchmany()
```

It gave me just One for Some reasons !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, 1 is considered "many"! Use `fetchmany(size=2)` if you want to fetch the next `2` rows.

If you want all the rows, just use `fetchall()` instead.

Comment: I upvote ur answer after 5mins because it's not letting me doing it

Comment: by the way, its giving me ('type',) how can I make it to just "type"

Comment: Use `[0]` to get the first element from the tuple.

Comment: I did use [0], But It still give me (type,) instead of "type"

Comment: New problem, new question please. Include the full code needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I can't I have to wait 90mins for It !